# Illegal assignment from Schema.SObjectField - apex code

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-controller

Do I have to load that in List only ?
I'm coming from .Net background and still learning how does the SF works...

PS: Schedule__c is a custom object and trying to access the field from.

> Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Schema.SObjectField to
>   String at line 26 column 9

```
 public PageReference SearchNow()
 {
      String interval_value = Schedule__c.Interval__c;
      //do more stuffs here 
 }
```

Comment: @Abu it looks like you may need to post more details about the issue. Actually what you are trying to do, here how your are fetching the value from Schedule__c.Interval before assigning to the sting.

Comment: Suri: thats my code believe it or not and i am trying to test how to get the `Schedule__c.Interval__c` data field value

Comment: See the link in the first comment. To pull a value from the database you have to execute a select e.g. `String interval_value = [select Interval__c from Schedule__c where ...].Interval__c;`. The value `Schedule__c.Interval__c` is just a token for a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code 'Schedule__c' , You can consider it synonym to `class` and Interval__c is `class member` defined to hold data.

So, if you want to get data, you need to create object of Class or retrieve value in this object using [SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm).

Here is psedo code :

```
//After where clause you need to provide some condition to fetch record from DB
Schedule__c scRecord = [SELECT Interval__c FROM  Schedule__c  WHERE ...];

//One you get record, read its value
String interval_value = scRecord.Interval__c ;
```

Comment: You can use a list variable if you are likely to get more than 1 records  like   List<Schedule__c> scRecord = [SELECT Interval__c FROM  Schedule__c  WHERE ...];                                                                                                        Or you can limit the results in your query itself using Limit 1.